# No matching function for call : const pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, image-processing, reference

I have the following function declaration

```
int vectorQuantization(const Color **input, Color **output,
                       const int rows, const int cols, const int numColors);
```

and when I try to call it from my main function I get the error "No matching function for call to 'VectorQuantization' ".

```
Color *input2quantize;
Color *outputQuantized;
...
...
vectorQuantization(&input2quantize, &outputQuantized, rows, cols, 10);
```

What I was trying to do is to make the **input** of the function constant so that it cannot be modified inside the function and I thought that declaring it as constant would make it.
What am I missing here? I was thinking about using references instead pointer to pointer, but I got confused. So two questions:

1. How can I fix this error?
2. Is it better to use references instead of const pointer to pointer?

Comment: vectorQuantization((const Color &)input2quantize, &outputQuantized, (const int)rows, (const int)cols, (const int)10);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say this:

```
typedef Color * ColorPtr;

ColorPtr input2quantize;

int vectorQuantization(ColorPtr const * input);

vectorQuantization(&input2quantize);
```

If you like, you can spell the function argument type out as `Color * const * input`, too.

Note that this protects you from having the function change the *pointer*, not the *pointee*, which cannot be protected, since you have a mutable pointer. If you wanted, you'd need a separate type:

```
typedef Color const * SafeColorPtr;

SafeColorPtr safeinput = input2quantize;

int foo(SafeColorPtr const * pInput);

foo(&safeinput);
```

Comment: Actually, the pointee can be protected if the pointer is protected as well. `T**` can't convert to `const T**`, but it can convert to `const T * const *`.

Comment: Very much appreciated. I understand what you mean but can I change (would it be a good idea) to use references instead of pointer to pointer? What would be the best choice (or both are good)?

Comment: Probably I'm getting off topic but I want to ask, what's the difference between `const int *imgIn`and `int const *imgIn` ?, putting the **const** before or after the data type?

Comment: well in this case there's no difference as both are before *

Comment: @BRabbit27: Well, yes, you should use references and vectors and no naked pointers at all. But I just took what you gave us and went from there. I'd never write code like that myself...